# How to install a downloaded Ruby gem file?

Tags: rubygems

How does "gem install" works ? It is not intuitive...

My gem is really here :

```
[root@localhost Téléchargement]# ll *.gem
-rw-rw-r-- 1 jean jean 16353818 mar  5 11:39 ruby-processing-1.0.9.gem
```

But an idiomatic "gem install" does not see it...

```
[root@localhost Téléchargement]# gem install  ruby-processing-1.0.9.gem 
ERROR:  could not find gem ruby-processing-1.0.9.gem locally or in a repository
```

What's wrong with that ?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Maybe I have not fully understood the question. But if you just want to install a gem that you have on your local machine, all you need to do from the console is go into the directory containing your gem and `gem install --local your.gem`.

Answer (score 27):

Just some more clarification in case you need to build / install your own gem file in this example foo-bar.

```
gem build foo-bar.gemspec
gem install --local foo-bar-0.1.0.gem
```

I was researching how to do this and this post was first result :)

Comment: Thanks. Second line should be probably fixed to: gem install --local foo-bar-1.0.0.gem

Comment: @valk well it depends on version specified in `*.gemspec`. Worth of mentioning is that you do not need `--local` handle but documentation says it does so I've respected it.

Comment: @HarisKrajina It is helpful to have `--local` because it stops it from checking each source for the repo and save a bit of time. Particularly useful if you have edited a gem found online (Did this to make it compatible with another program).

Answer (score 13):

The problem is that *gem install* is looking for gems to install in its default directory. You can find out where that is by running:

```
$ gem environment
```

This will give you something like:

```
> RubyGems Environment:
>   - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.3.6
>   - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.6 (2007-09-24 patchlevel 111) [i486-linux]
>   - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
>   - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.8
>   - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/bin
>   - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
>     - ruby
>     - x86-linux
>   - GEM PATHS:
>      - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
>      - /home/adminuser/.gem/ruby/1.8
```

The **GEM PATHS** locations is where *gem install* is expecting to find gems to install. So, the solution to your problem would be to copy the gem from its current location to the expected directory, i.e.

```
$ cp my.gem /home/adminuser/.gem/ruby/1.8/
```

If you then run *gem install* it will pick up your gem and install it. Make sure you run the copy command as superuser (sudo, if you're running Ubuntu like me)

**P.S** If, when you run *$ gem environment*, you get an "undefined method ‘manage_gems’ for Gem:Module (NoMethodError)" error, then edit */usr/bin/gem* and ensure that the first three lines of the file look like this:

1. require 'rubygems'
2. require 'rubygems/gem_runner'
3. ## Gem.manage_gems

Comment: I'm trying to install a gem from source, how would I do that? Preferably with a symlink so I can update the source.

Comment: Thanks for this. I need to install the Oracle adapter and had to do it from the .gem file as the source is no longer available.