# Installing Nokogiri (v.1.5.0.) Gem In Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: rubygems, nokogiri, ubuntu-12.10

I am trying to install foodcritic gem on Ubuntu 12.10. It could be successfully installed in Ubuntu 12.04. I have installed the requirements: *libxslt-dev*, *libxml2-dev*, *ruby1.9.3* and *make* packages. But when now I try

```
sudo gem install foodcritic
```

I get the following error:

```
compiling xml_xpath_context.c
xml_xpath_context.c: In function ‘xpath_generic_exception_handler’:
xml_xpath_context.c:184:3: error: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Werror=format-security]
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make: *** [xml_xpath_context.o] Error 1

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.5.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.5.0/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out
```

Nokogiri-1.5.0 gem is a requirement for foodcritic and it is it's instllation that fails.
How can I install foodcritic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for Ubuntu 12.10 (or any Debian-based system that uses `-Werror=format-security`) was built into nokogiri-1.5.4. I recommend installing the latest (currently 1.5.5). It should be compatible with 1.5.0, except with more fixed bugs :) See the [changelog](http://nokogiri.org/CHANGELOG_rdoc.html) for more information.

It looks like `foodcritic` locked the version to 1.5.0 because of a segfault in 1.5.3 (according to *its* [changelog](https://github.com/acrmp/foodcritic/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)) but one of the fixes in 1.5.4 fixes a segfault, so you may want to modify the gem to require `~> 1.5.4` and if it works, contact the author of the gem.

Comment: Good, thanks. I downloaded gem (http://rubygems.org/gems/foodcritic), changed requirements in metadata (nokogiri~>1.5.4) and acted according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386996/how-to-install-a-downloaded-ruby-gem-file